# Flagging answer in First Posts review doesn't enable "I'm Done" if post is deleted immediately

Tags: bug, status-norepro, flags, review

Pretty simple: flagging an answer while using the First Posts review page doesn't enable the "I'm Done" button. I'm under the impression that flagging a first post would be the type of action encouraged in the review process and consequentially I conclude this is not intentional and is therefore an error.

**UPDATE:**

Okay, it seems that this issue happens *only* when the post is immediately deleted (denoted by the "this post has been deleted" message). I *do not* have this issue when the post is flagged but not immediately deleted.

Still, this sounds like a bug.

Comment: Is the answer that you flagged the post under review, or are you flagging an answer to a question that is under review?  Anytime I've flagged a post that was under review it has been considered an action.

Comment: I have even seen that if you happen to have flagged the post before entering the review section, the "I'm Done" button is turned on immediately.

Comment: @Servy, the answer (which is what I flagged) was under review. Please check my update.

Comment: If the post was just deleted it might not matter what action you took at all; it wouldn't surprise me if the fact that it was deleted while you were trying to review it prevented you from completing the review.  This may or may not be a bug.

Comment: @Servy, no, no. My flag caused it to be deleted. I don't know the criteria but I think if multiple people flag the answer the same it gets deleted based on votes or rep or something. But it was my flag that caused the deletion.

Comment: @JustinSatyr That might not matter.  It's plausible that deleted posts can't be reviewed at all.  I also think that auto-deletion of content from flags is only for comments, not questions.  My guess is a mod was just quicker to delete the post than you were to click "I'm done".

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have a local bug/glitch, as when I flag the questions in the review for first posts, the "I'm done" button still becomes displayed, and useable.

I would recommend

- Make sure that [Flash is up to date](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/find-version-flash-player.html)
- Make sure that the browser you use supports the HTML version that 
  stackExchange servers use (HTML5, I believe, is not supported for IE versions 7 and below, chrome around version 6, and firefox around version 3.6) [HTML5 browser report card](http://html5test.com/index.html)
- Clear temporary items/cookies for SO

Comment: No, I didn't give enough detail initially. Please check my update.

Answer (score 0):

I tried flagging answers (thus triggering immediate deletion of the answer), but I was unable to reproduce this in Chrome, Firefox, or IE.

Any more specific information (e.g. browser version, or which post you were flagging) would be very helpful in tracking this down.